# NUnit VS Adapter do not discover tests due to FileNotFoundException, Exception converting tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, mstest, typemock

When trying to run tests via Visual Studio Test Explorer, I got following error for all tests in solution (those that use Typemock and those that don't):

> [2/12/2018 11:35:36 AM Informational] NUnit VS Adapter 2.1.1.0 discovering tests is started
>   [2/12/2018 11:35:37 AM Error] Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException, Exception converting Manager.Tests.MessageLoggerTest.AddMessage_WhenAddMessageIsCalled_ThenAddMessagesToList
>   ...

I found only one mention of the problem online on Xamarin forum, but with no fix (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119513/xamarin-ui-tests-filenotfoundexception).

I use `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, version 15.5.6`, `NUnit 2.6.4`, `NUnitTestAdapter 2.1.1` and `Typemock 8.6.0.22`.

Running tests via Typemock runner (Test Navigator) works as expected.

**EDIT**

I feel a bit embarrassed, I cannot reproduce my original error. At work, we use multiple branches of the code base. Now, one branch works fine. I can discover and run tests via VS runner (Test Explorer).

On the other branch, when rebuild 1. test project I am getting `StackOverflowException` instead of `FileNotFoundException`. But it also discovers 41 of 43 tests that are in project. The 2. test project get also `StackOverflowException` and discovers none of 295 tests.

> [2/20/2018 10:43:40 AM Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
>   [2/20/2018 10:43:44 AM Informational] NUnit VS Adapter 2.1.1.0 discovering tests is started
>   [2/20/2018 10:43:54 AM Error] The active test discovery was aborted. Reason: Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
>
> [2/20/2018 10:43:54 AM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 41 found (0:00:13.8969695) ==========

Have compared `solution` file, `project` files and `NuGet` package configs. Only difference between the branches was `packages.config` line:

`<package id="Typemock.Isolator" version="8.6.0.18" targetFramework="net452" />`

The working branch have `targetFramework="net452"`, failing branch had `targetFramework="net462"`. However changing framework to `net452` didn't help.

Will have to dig deeper to see, what makes the difference. Thanks for anyone's help and time.

Comment: Can you upload a small repro project for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the NUnit 2 Test Adapter extension for Visual Studio from the gallery.  This fixed the issue for me on a project also using NUnit 2.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. 
In my case deleting temporary files in windows solved my issue.

Close visual studio. Go to Run and type %temp%. Clear all the files. Now the visual studio 
will discover all the UI test case.